# Attempting to open CD tray

Tags: c++, winapi, mci

I'm trying to open and close the CD tray of my computer using a piece of code. I have been using MCI commands and have included `winmm.lib` in the additional dependencies of my project configuration. I've included `windows.h` and `mmsystem.h` as well.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
mciSendCommand(0, MCI_SET, MCI_SET_DOOR_OPEN, NULL);
mciSendCommand(1, MCI_SET, MCI_SET_DOOR_CLOSED, NULL);
```

The code builds and runs fine, there's just no CD tray action going on! Can anyone suggest how I need to adapt this?

Comment: It is operating system specific. You probably need to tag with `windows` or `win32` your question.

Comment: You need to check the return values of those function calls for error codes.

Comment: Is `0` valid as a device id?

Comment: It's running in a win32 console. How would I check those return values? Alex when I looked it up 0 indicates device is close and 1 indicates open.

Comment: You should be using MCI_OPEN to get the device ID - not just plugging in 0 and 1. Doc indicates that this is complicated too...

Comment: Or you can use the mcisendstring version with "set cdaudio door open"

Answer (score 6):

If you have multiple CD-Drives you should use the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <tchar.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  

int _tmain() 
{ 
   DWORD dwBytes; 
   HANDLE hCdRom = CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\M:"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); 
   if (hCdRom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   { 
     _tprintf(_T("Error: %x"), GetLastError()); 
     return 1; 
   } 

   // Open the door:  
   DeviceIoControl(hCdRom, IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwBytes, NULL); 

   Sleep(1000); 

   // Close the door:  
   DeviceIoControl(hCdRom, IOCTL_STORAGE_LOAD_MEDIA, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwBytes, NULL); 

   CloseHandle(hCdRom); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing some steps, first you need to open the device.

Try this:

```
#pragma comment( lib, "winmm.lib" )

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>


int _tmain()
{

    MCI_OPEN_PARMS mPar = { 0 };
    mPar.lpstrDeviceType = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(MCI_DEVTYPE_CD_AUDIO);

    // Open device
    mciSendCommand(0, MCI_OPEN, MCI_OPEN_TYPE | MCI_OPEN_TYPE_ID, (DWORD)&mPar);

    // Open tray
    mciSendCommand(mPar.wDeviceID, MCI_SET, MCI_SET_DOOR_OPEN, 0);

    // Close tray
    mciSendCommand(mPar.wDeviceID, MCI_SET, MCI_SET_DOOR_CLOSED, 0);

    // Close device
    mciSendCommand(mPar.wDeviceID, MCI_CLOSE, MCI_WAIT, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using DevC++ IDE (WINDOWS ONLY)

Then follow steps:

Step 1:
File > Project > Console Application << Enter

Step 2:
Project Options > Parameters > Linker > write "-lWinmm" in Linker << Enter

Step 3: Open cdtray Copy and paste this small code in your IDE. I recommend DevC++ for this one..

```
#include<windows.h>
int main(){
mciSendString("set cdaudio door open",0,0,0);
}
```

Step 4: Close tray, Just change door 'open' to 'closed'

```
 mciSendString("set cdaudio door closed",0,0,0);
```